# Does the program terminate after a called method finishes, or does it return control to the calling function?

Tags: java

This is a question from a Java course at the college I attend. My teacher says the answer is D - "The program terminates", but I think the answer is C - "Control is returned to method C".

What's the correct answer, and why?

> If method A calls method B, and method B calls method C, and method C calls method D,
>   when method D finishes, what happens?
>
> A. Control is returned to method A
>
> B. Control is returned to method B
>
> C. Control is returned to method C
>
> D. The program terminates

Comment: You're right. Rather ask your teacher for a clarification on his/her answer, and keep your point in front of him/her.

Comment: If that's the question then you're right

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct for the question that you have posted. Ask your prof for an explanation

Comment: What does terminate mean...does the code crash....or the processing of function D is completed.

Comment: write a program that replicates this situation and show your prof

Comment: Terminate means the program exits.

Comment: Your right, the question is actually a pretty bad question.  Who says the call to method D is the last method invoked?  What if after calling D, C calls method A causing some recursion.  If your prof fights you on this you may want to consider a transfer.

Comment: @RohitJain This is the response I received. I have received several questions concerning question 7 on the Methods  Assessment.   Each method (A,B,C,D) sequentially calls the "Next" method.  When Method D ends, it returns control to Method C, which then ends and returns control to Method B, etc......eventually control returns to main which then terminates the program.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert Okay, your instructor is being a massive jerk then. The question asks what happens when METHOD D finishes, not when the entire sequence of events finishes. He's phrased the question poorly if that's his response.

Comment: @ChrisAlbert So you spoke with him?  Its not like he just circled the wrong answer?  You are in a for a long semester buddy.

Comment: @KevinBowersox I did speak with him about it and he has told me I am wrong twice now.

Comment: I can't find any mention of method A called from main() in the description. So asserting that the program terminates makes an assumption that might be true, but it isn't in the majority of cases. Any software I've worked on has at least a case where there are sequential calls like that, with a depth of 4 or more. And fortunately the app won't terminate in such cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is c, unless method D causes program to terminate, then the answer is d.

The behavior of a method call is well-defined in the definition of `invokevirtual` opcode (operation code). From [Java Virtual Machine Online Instruction Reference](http://cs.au.dk/~mis/dOvs/jvmspec/ref--35.html):

> `invokevirtual` dispatches a Java method. It is used in Java to invoke
>   all methods except interface methods (which use `invokeinterface`),
>   static methods (which use `invokestatic`), and the few special cases
>   handled by `invokespecial`.
>
> For example, when you write in Java:
>
> ```
> Object x;
> ...
> x.equals("hello");
> ```
>
> this is compiled into something like:
>
> ```
> aload_1       ; push local variable 1 (i.e. 'x') onto stack
> ldc "hello"   ; push the string "hello" onto stack
>
> ; invoke the equals method
> invokevirtual java/lang/Object/equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
> ; the boolean result is now on the stack
> ```
>
> Once a method has been located, invokevirtual calls the method. (...)
>   When the method called by invokevirtual returns, any single (or
>   double) word return result is placed on the operand stack of the
>   current method **and execution continues at the instruction that
>   follows invokevirtual in the bytecode**.

Answer (score 1):

the only way to terminate (barring an Abnormal Termination) is for execution chain to complete.  Your answer makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's what i hate on these kind of questions. It depends on how the program works. If D has a command that forces the program to terminate, e.g. `break`, ofc the rogram terminates, but it might have that kind of call that it give control from D over to C, in where C tries to call another command, if not, gives control over B, which maybe has another command and tries calling something else, if not it gives control over A.

If it's a plane command, yes, the program terminates, if not, well, it can be 'c', or 'b', or 'a'.

Comment: `break` doesn't force program to terminate in Java.

Comment: It was just an example. But in Python it does at some level.